# estoy hacendo algo mal en el programa pero no lo veo

Tags: python

me piden lo siguiente
Realizar un programa que conste de una clase Persona con dos atributos
nombre y edad. Los atributos se introducirán por teclado y habrá otro
método para imprimir los datos.
Declarar una segunda clase llama Empleado que hereda de la clase
Persona y agrega el atributo sueldo. Debe mostrar si tiene que pagar
impuestos o no (sueldo superior a 3000).
Crear un objeto de cada clase.

Especificaciones
 Implementa tu programa en un archivo con el nombre
herencia_num2.py.
 Declarar las clases y sus atributos.
 Debe crear un objeto de cada clase.
 Imprimir si el empleado debe pagar impuestos o no.

yo he hecho el siguiente programa

```
#herencia_num2.py (foo)
class Persona: (foo)
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad): (foo) 
        self.nombre = nombre (foo)
        self.edad= edad (foo)
    nombre = input ("escribe tu nombre")(foo) 
    edad = int(input("escribe tu edad"))(foo)
def __repr__(self):(foo)
        return(f"{self.nombre} {self.edad}" )(foo)
class Empleado(Persona):(foo)
    def __init__(self, sueldo):(foo)
        self.sueldo=sueldo(foo)
    sueldo = int(input("escibe tu sueldo"))(foo)
    if sueldo>=3000:(foo)
        def __repr__(self):(foo)
        print(f"{self.nombre} {self.edad} no has de pagar impuestos") (foo)
    else:(foo)
        print(f"{self.nombre} {self.edad} si has de pagar impuestos") (foo)
```

pero me da error. Y no se ve el fallo qu eestoy cometiendo.
¿me podeis decir que esta mal?
mil graciass

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En la ayuda esta todo ;)

Comment: Que error te da? porque decis que da error, pero no que error te da

Comment: ¿Qué son todos esos `(foo)` que aparecen al final de cada línea?

Comment: lo de los foo es lo que me han dicho que ponga en esta pagina para los cambios de linea. Lo mismo me han tomado el pelo y se estan riendo de mi